# Acerca de suma de matrices

Tags: java, matrices

[image: exactamente lo que pide el profesor]

mi profesor: matriz donde el programa pedirá al usuario el número de filas y columnas de la tabla, será la misma magnitud tanto para columnas y filas. La tabla se rellenará pendiéndole valor a valor al usuario. Además, el programa tendrá que sumar todas las filas en diagonal y mostrarlo en pantalla.

Comment: Bienvenida a [es.so]. **¡Aquí no hacemos tareas!** Lee [ask] y muéstranos qué has intentado, si llegaras a tener algún error con tu código

Comment: Pon lo que has intentado para poderte ayudar

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes. ¿Cuál es tu pregunta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bienvenida Valentina, te dejo aquí un ejemplo de como lo haría yo.

Pero la próxima vez deberías de mostrarnos lo que has intentado y dónde te has quedado para poderte ayudar mejor con tu problema.

Espero que te sirva.

```
import java.util.*;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        //scanner para la entrada de datos
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        //variable donde almacenaremos el total del valor de la diagonal del array
        int total = 0;

        //se pide la cantidad de filas y columnas
        System.out.print("Ingrese la cantidad de filas y columnas: ");
        int cantidad = in.nextInt();

        //se crea el array con la cantidad de filas y columnas que se ha introducido
        int[][] miArray = new int[cantidad][cantidad];

        //se llena el array pidiendo 1 por 1 los datos, y se va sumando la cantidad resultante de la diagonal
        for(int i = 0; i < cantidad; i++){
            for(int o = 0; o < cantidad; o++){
                System.out.print("Ingrese el valor de la celda " + i + " - " + o + ": ");
                miArray[i][o] = in.nextInt();
            }
            total += miArray[i][i]; //se suma al total el valor de la posicion [i][i]

        }

        System.out.print("El total del valor diagonal es de: " + total);

    }
}
```

Comment: Buenas, te recomendaría que no respondas preguntas que no presenten análisis o estudio previo, pues en estos casos, lo que parece es que busca la solución para un ejercicio de clase.